How to "grow" only half axis-range in SciChart?
I'm trying to create a chart with a fixed y-range (0;120) and a dynamic x-range, depending what element I selected in a list. With the left-click of the mouse it's possible to zoom in.
The chart react also to the double-clicked of the mouse, to restore the default ranges.
The problem is that the default ranges are not what I defined in the code:
public class PeakChartFactory : IPeakChartFactory
{
    private static readonly DoubleRange DefaultXRange = new (0, 120);

    private DoubleRange _CreateXRange(IEnumerable<double> xValues)
    {
        var minX = xValues.Min();
        var maxX = xValues.Max();
        return new DoubleRange(minX, maxX);
    }

    [...]
}

 public class PeakChartViewModel : BindableBase
 {
     #region Attributes and Properties
     private IRange? _visibleXRange;
     public IRange? VisibleXRange
     {
         get => _visibleXRange;
         set => SetProperty(ref _visibleXRange, value);
     }
     private IRange? _visibleYRange;
     public IRange? VisibleYRange
     {
         get => _visibleYRange;
         set => SetProperty(ref _visibleYRange, value);
     }
     private ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeries> _renderableSeries;
     public ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeries> RenderableSeries
     {
         get => _renderableSeries;
         set => SetProperty(ref _renderableSeries, value);
     }
     private DefaultViewportManager _viewPortManager;
     public DefaultViewportManager ViewPortManager
     {
         get => _viewPortManager;
         set => SetProperty(ref _viewPortManager, value);
     }
     #endregion Attributes and Properties

     public PeakChartViewModel()
     {
         RenderableSeries = new ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeries>();
         ViewPortManager = new ReferenceCardViewportManager(this);
     }
 }

public class PeakChartViewModelMapper : IPeakChartViewModelMapper
{
    public PeakChartViewModel PeakChartViewModel { get; }
    public PeakChartViewModelMapper(PeakChartViewModel peakChartViewModel)
    {
        PeakChartViewModel = peakChartViewModel;
    }

    public void Map(ReferenceCard referenceCard)
    {
        PeakChartViewModel.VisibleXRange = new DoubleRange(0, 120);
        PeakChartViewModel.RenderableSeries.Clear();

        if (referenceCard.RenderableSeries == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        PeakChartViewModel.VisibleXRange = referenceCard.XRange;
        PeakChartViewModel.RenderableSeries.Add(referenceCard.RenderableSeries);
    }
}


When I double-clicked the chart ranges are restored by taking the min-max of x-y values.
Instead I'd like to get an extra space on x-axis (both directions) and an extra space on y-axis (only top-half).
I used the GrowBy() method but this expands the axis-range on both direction.
